# how to search in mongodb by query filter

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a table on my website where users can type in a word in a search field, and I want mongodb to search for those words in specific objects and return only matching objects. The search text is sent in the request query.

I use the following code for pagination, but the search feature is missing.

```
const result = await orders.aggregate([
      { $facet: {
        rows: [
          { $match: { status: {
            $in: ['received', 'packing', 'packed', 'fulfilled', 'rejected', 'withdrawn'],
          },
          } },
          { $skip: offsetPage * parseInt(req.query.rowsPerPage) },
          { $limit: parseInt(req.query.rowsPerPage) },
          { $project: {
            record: 1,
            status: 1,
            onPalette: 1,
            note: 1,
            grossTotal: 1,
            receivedLog: 1,
            arrivalDate: 1,
            partner: 1,
            location: 1,
          } },
        ],
        count: [
          { $count: 'count' },
        ],
      } },
    ]).toArray();
```

I would like to search in the "record" field which is a number, and in a partner's name "partner.name" which is a string.

If no search query sent, or the search query (req.query.filter) is an empty string just return everything

Answer (score 1):

```
{ "_id" : 1, "location" : "24th Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "apples", "oranges", "bananas" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "location" : "36th Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "bananas", "pears", "grapes" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "location" : "82nd Street",
  "in_stock" : [ "cantaloupes", "watermelons", "apples" ] }
db.fruit.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "store location" : "$location",
      "has bananas" : {
        $in: [ "bananas", "$in_stock" ]
      }
    }
  }
])
OUTPUT --
{ "_id" : 1, "store location" : "24th Street", "has bananas" : true }
{ "_id" : 2, "store location" : "36th Street", "has bananas" : true }
{ "_id" : 3, "store location" : "82nd Street", "has bananas" : false }
```